# State name should be text box when country is Other than United States and France in magento checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, magento-1.7

In magento checkout page, the state should be a text box except for the countries **United States** and **France.**

If the country is **United States/France**, the regions are displayed in drop down. (the default functionality).

If The selected country is Canada, the drop down displayed with the regions.  Instead of drop down, text box should be displayed.

Comment: *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.*

Comment: Edited just now. Are you clear?@Hashem Qolami

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to delete the states for Canada, you have to manually go to the database and edit the table of `directory_country_region` and then you have to manually delete the rows which contain the `country_id` as `CA`.  Then automatically in front end, if you select `canada`, the dropdown will turn into text box.

Comment: I have already done that.  But I need the drop down in magneto admin panel->Add/Edit customer page.  Is there is any other solution?